# Change MainWindow widget from button inside QWidget inside MainWindow

Tags: python, linux, qt, ubuntu, pyqt

So i have an empty main frame called `MainWindow` and a `WelcomeWidget` that gets called immidiatley on program startup and loads inside the main frame. Then i want the button `next_btn` inside `WelcomeWidget` to call `LicenseWidget` QWidget inside the `MainWindow` class . How do i do that?

Here is my code:

**Main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  Main.py
#  
#  Copyright 2015 Ognjen Galic <gala@thinkpad>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from WelcomeWidget import Ui_welcome_widget
from LicenseWidget import Ui_license_widget
import sys

class WelcomeWidget(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_welcome_widget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WelcomeWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cancel_btn.pressed.connect(self.close)
        self.next_btn.pressed.connect(self.license_show)

    def close(self):
        sys.exit(0)

    def license_show(self):
        mainWindow.cw = LicenseWidget(self)
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.cw)

class LicenseWidget(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_license_widget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LicenseWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        mainWindow.cw = WelcomeWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = mainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

**LicenseWidget.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'LicenseWidget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_license_widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, license_widget):
        license_widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("license_widget"))
        license_widget.resize(640, 420)
        license_widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 420))
        license_widget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 420))
        self.frame_btn = QtGui.QFrame(license_widget)
        self.frame_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 365, 641, 56))
        self.frame_btn.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_btn.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame_btn"))
        self.no_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_btn)
        self.no_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 15, 87, 26))
        self.no_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("no_btn"))
        self.yes_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_btn)
        self.yes_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 15, 87, 26))
        self.yes_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yes_btn"))
        self.back_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_btn)
        self.back_btn.setEnabled(True)
        self.back_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(346, 15, 87, 26))
        self.back_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.back_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("back_btn"))
        self.main_frame = QtGui.QFrame(license_widget)
        self.main_frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 75))
        self.main_frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(8, 0))
        self.main_frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.main_frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.main_frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("main_frame"))
        self.Title = QtGui.QLabel(self.main_frame)
        self.Title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 5, 311, 61))
        self.Title.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Title"))
        self.license_cont = QtGui.QTextEdit(license_widget)
        self.license_cont.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 74, 640, 260))
        self.license_cont.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("license_cont"))
        self.agree_or_not = QtGui.QLabel(license_widget)
        self.agree_or_not.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 340, 621, 17))
        self.agree_or_not.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("agree_or_not"))

        self.retranslateUi(license_widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(license_widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, license_widget):
        license_widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("license_widget", "Form", None))
        self.no_btn.setText(_translate("license_widget", "No", None))
        self.yes_btn.setText(_translate("license_widget", "Yes", None))
        self.back_btn.setText(_translate("license_widget", "Back", None))
        self.Title.setText(_translate("license_widget", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600;\">Program License</span></p><p>Please read the license carefully</p></body></html>", None))
        self.license_cont.setHtml(_translate("license_widget", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Droid Sans\'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">example license</p></body></html>", None))
        self.agree_or_not.setText(_translate("license_widget", "Do you agree to the license? If you click \"No\", the installer will close.", None))
```

**WelcomeWidget.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'WelcomeWidget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_welcome_widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, welcome_widget):
        welcome_widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("welcome_widget"))
        welcome_widget.resize(640, 420)
        welcome_widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 420))
        welcome_widget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 420))
        self.side_pixmap = QtGui.QLabel(welcome_widget)
        self.side_pixmap.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 220, 365))
        self.side_pixmap.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.side_pixmap.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("media/InstallShield.png")))
        self.side_pixmap.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("side_pixmap"))
        self.welcome_frame = QtGui.QFrame(welcome_widget)
        self.welcome_frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 365, 641, 56))
        self.welcome_frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.welcome_frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.welcome_frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("welcome_frame"))
        self.cancel_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.welcome_frame)
        self.cancel_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 15, 87, 26))
        self.cancel_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cancel_btn"))
        self.next_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.welcome_frame)
        self.next_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 15, 87, 26))
        self.next_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("next_btn"))
        self.back_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.welcome_frame)
        self.back_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.back_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(346, 15, 87, 26))
        self.back_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("back_btn"))
        self.welcome_header = QtGui.QLabel(welcome_widget)
        self.welcome_header.setEnabled(True)
        self.welcome_header.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 10, 361, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.welcome_header.setFont(font)
        self.welcome_header.setWordWrap(True)
        self.welcome_header.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("welcome_header"))
        self.welcome_desc = QtGui.QLabel(welcome_widget)
        self.welcome_desc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 120, 391, 51))
        self.welcome_desc.setWordWrap(True)
        self.welcome_desc.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("welcome_desc"))

        self.retranslateUi(welcome_widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(welcome_widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, welcome_widget):
        welcome_widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("welcome_widget", "Form", None))
        self.cancel_btn.setText(_translate("welcome_widget", "Cancel", None))
        self.next_btn.setText(_translate("welcome_widget", "Next", None))
        self.back_btn.setText(_translate("welcome_widget", "Back", None))
        self.welcome_header.setText(_translate("welcome_widget", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Welcome to the InstallShield wizard for Google Chrome.</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.welcome_desc.setText(_translate("welcome_widget", "<html><head/><body><p>This install wizard will install Google Chrome to your computer. To continue press Next.</p></body></html>", None))
```

**MainWindow.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MainWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(640, 420)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 420))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 420))
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        MainWindow.setAnimated(False)
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.main_widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("main_widget"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "InstallShield Wizard", None))
```

If this worked straight out of the WelcomeWidget class and told the MainWindow class that would be awesome.

```
 class WelcomeWidget(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_welcome_widget):
    [ ... ]
    def license_show(self):
        mainWindow.cw = LicenseWidget(self)
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
```

Someone with an answer gets an e-cookie!

Comment: Actually can't use QWizardPage ?

Answer (score 1):

`QWizard` might be of use. Another way would be to layout both widgets in a `QVerticalLayout` and hide the one you are not interested in. The visible one takes then up all the space.

It could even be completely constructed in QtCreator .. just `hide()` what you don't want to see and `show()` what you want to see.

It is possible to build complex layouts with lots of widgets in the QtCreator and show only what's necessary for the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  Main.py
#  
#  Copyright 2015 Ognjen Galic <gala@thinkpad>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from MainWidget import Ui_main_widget
from WelcomeWidget import Ui_welcome_widget
from LicenseWidget import Ui_license_widget
import sys

class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        mainWindow.welcomeWidget = WelcomeWidget(self)
        mainWindow.licenseWidget = LicenseWidget(self)
        mainWindow.mainWidget = MainWidget(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

        self.mainWidget.addWidget(self.welcomeWidget)

        self.welcomeWidget.next_btn.pressed.connect(self.license_show)
        self.welcomeWidget.cancel_btn.pressed.connect(self.close_cancel)

        self.licenseWidget.cancel_btn.pressed.connect(self.close_cancel)
        self.licenseWidget.back_btn.pressed.connect(self.go_back)

        self.licenseWidget.i_do.toggled.connect(self.accept_license)
        self.licenseWidget.i_dont.toggled.connect(self.dont_accept_license)

    def go_back(self):
            self.mainWidget.removeWidget(self.licenseWidget)
            self.mainWidget.addWidget(self.welcomeWidget)

    def close_cancel(self):
            sys.exit(0)

    def license_show(self):
            self.mainWidget.removeWidget(self.welcomeWidget)
            self.mainWidget.addWidget(self.licenseWidget) 

    def accept_license(self):
            self.licenseWidget.next_btn.setEnabled(True)
    def dont_accept_license(self):
            self.licenseWidget.next_btn.setEnabled(False)


class WelcomeWidget(QtGui.QStackedWidget, Ui_welcome_widget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WelcomeWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self, "Linux 2.6.32.68")

class LicenseWidget(QtGui.QStackedWidget, Ui_license_widget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LicenseWidget, self).__init__()
        license_file = open("license.html")
        license_text_file = license_file.read()
        self.setupUi(self, license_text_file)

class MainWidget(QtGui.QStackedWidget, Ui_main_widget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = mainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

This works. Thanks to anyone who helped.